# JavaScript for loop increment not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to use [this timeline](http://codepen.io/ritz078/pen/LGRWjE/) 
But currently it calculate Navigation 'left' value based on the date difference.

I'm trying to make the left value increment by 25, so nav items will have 'left' value 25, 50, 75...

Here what I tried, but it's not working-

```
function setDatePosition(timelineComponents, min) {
        for (i = 0; i < timelineComponents['timelineDates'].length; i++) { 
            var distance = daydiff(timelineComponents['timelineDates'][0], timelineComponents['timelineDates'][i]),
                distanceNorm = Math.round(distance/timelineComponents['eventsMinLapse']) + 2;
            timelineComponents['timelineEvents'].eq(i).css('left', distanceNorm*min+'px');
        }
    }
```

to

```
function setDatePosition(timelineComponents, min) {
        for (i = 0; i < timelineComponents['timelineDates'].length; i += 25) { 
            var distance = daydiff(timelineComponents['timelineDates'][0], timelineComponents['timelineDates'][i]),
                distanceNorm = Math.round(distance/timelineComponents['eventsMinLapse']) + 2;
            timelineComponents['timelineEvents'].eq(i).css('left', i +'%');
        }
    }
```

How can I make the left value increment by 25 instead of current date difference calculation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that you are trying to access i-th element of timelineComponents['timelineEvents'] (by using  timelineComponents['timelineEvents'].eq(i)). As you specified that i increases for 25 each loop, this means that you'll access element 0, element 25, element 50, etc. What I believe you're trying to do is access every element, just make the 'left' property increase by i (in px?)

So your function would look something like this:

```
  function setDatePosition(timelineComponents, min) {
            var position = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < timelineComponents['timelineDates'].length; i++) { 
                var distance = daydiff(timelineComponents['timelineDates'][0], timelineComponents['timelineDates'][i]),
                    distanceNorm = Math.round(distance/timelineComponents['eventsMinLapse']) + 2;
                timelineComponents['timelineEvents'].eq(i).css('left', position +'px');
                position += 25;
            }
        }
```

if you need it to increase by 25%  each time, just change the position + 'px' part to position + '%'